# errors when writing to a bin file

Tags: c

```
struct Seats seats[12];
FILE* inp;
FILE* opt;
int counter = 1;
char option;
if ((inp = fopen("seats.bin", "rb")) == NULL) {// open file to read
    printf("file did not open!");
    exit(0);
}
fread(&seats, sizeof(struct Seats), 12, inp);// save file data to struct array

//later in the code
opt = fopen("seats.bin", "w");
fwrite(seats, sizeof(struct Seats), 12, opt);
fclose(inp);
```

i have no problems reading the data from the bin file. however when i try to write to the file it stores  random values making it imposable to read when i boot up the program again.
if you guys know the problem i would appreciate the help

Comment: What is the structure definition?

Comment: You don't check if the fopen for writing succeeded, nor if the fread and fwrite succeeded, and you're passing `&seats` to fread and `seats` to fwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on `windows`, it's important to write `wb` instead of only `w` on this line `opt = fopen("seats.bin", "wb");` to refer to a `binary` file:

```
struct Seats seats[12];
FILE* inp;
FILE* opt;
int counter = 1;
char option;
if ((inp = fopen("seats.bin", "rb")) == NULL) {// open file to read
    printf("file did not open!");
    exit(0);
}
fread(&seats, sizeof(struct Seats), 12, inp);// save file data to struct array

//later in the code
opt = fopen("seats.bin", "wb");//w for write, b for binary
fwrite(seats, sizeof(struct Seats), 12, opt);
fclose(inp);
```

Comment: you were right. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how many you actually read and only write that many. Otherwise if you read fewer than you expect you'll write out whatever garbage was in `seats`.

```
size_t num_read = fread(seats, sizeof(struct Seats), 12, inp);

// later

fwrite(seats, sizeof(struct Seats), num_read, opt);
```

Also...

- Check `fopen` worked.
- Use `wb` for writing binary, like `rb`. It's only important on Windows machines.