# Why does C use 5 bytes to write/fwrite the number 10, but 4 bytes to write 9 or 11?

Tags: c, struct, fwrite

GCC on Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test {
    int n1;
    int n2;
};

int main() {
    FILE *f;
    
    f = fopen("test.dat", "w");
    struct test test1 = {10, 10};
    fwrite(&test1, sizeof(struct test), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    
    struct test test2;
    f = fopen("test.dat", "r");
    while(fread(&test2, sizeof(struct test), 1, f))
        printf("n1=%d n2=%d\n", test2.n1, test2.n2);
    fclose(f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I set test1 to `10,10` then fwrite will write **10 bytes** to file: `0D 0A 00 00 00 0D 0A 00 00 00`

*(each 4-byte int will be padded with a 0D carriage return character before it)*

If I set test1 to `11,11` then fwrite will write **8 bytes** to file: `0B 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00`

*(as I would expect)*

If I set test1 to `9,9` then fwrite will write **8 bytes** to file: `09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00`

*(as I would expect)*

If I set test1 to `9,10` then fwrite will write **9 bytes** to file: `09 00 00 00 0D 0A 00 00 00`

The 9 gets 4 bytes as expected, but the 10 gets padded with an extra **0D** byte, resulting in 5 bytes. What is so special about the number 10 that requires this padding? And why do both smaller and larger numbers (8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, etc) not get padded? I thought maybe GCC is confusing the number 10 for a new-line character (a new-line is 10 is acsii), but this does not explain how fread is able to get the number 10 back out correctly.

And how do I write a struct to file without getting this extra padding on the number 10?

Comment: Line ending translation when a file is opened in text mode. Open it in binary mode instead.

Comment: You're running it on Windows, right?

Comment: `f = fopen("test.dat", "wb");`

Comment: Use external tools like WinHex to see the output file. Now the problem is in your reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [errors when writing to a bin file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098455/errors-when-writing-to-a-bin-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You opened the file in *text* mode, so on Windows every `'\n'` character gets a carriage return prepended in front of it.

You should write (and read) binary data in *binary* mode instead (`fopen(..., "wb")`) -- this will be much faster, and avoids surprises (and also requires only 8 bytes, which is what `sizeof(struct test)` is).

> What is so special about the number 10 that requires this padding?

The number `10` just happens to be the ASCII code for a newline (`'\n'`) character.

Comment: Opening in "wb" mode fixed the problem. I am surprised C is able to get the 10 int back out correctly after doing that to the data.

Answer (score 8):

You are writing and reading in text mode.

Open the file with the flags "wb" and "rb". This will treat the files as binary files.